# Why does SAM3x8e work only with Atmel-Ice programmer connected?

Tags: arduino, arm, atmel-studio

I have DIY sam3x8e pcb board based on schematics of Arduino Due. I can program it with Atmel-Ice (jtag connector) in Atmel Studio with basic serial transfer example and it works fine when the Atmel-ice is plugged in to the board. But when I unplugged it, the MCU doesn`t work. What are possible reasons for that?

I tested all the voltages across Sam3x8e power pins and they are all correct.

Comment: Check the nTRST and nSRST pins on your JTAG connector. Maybe you have terminated them incorrectly and thus the board stays in some sort of reset condition. Without the Atmel-ICE connected I would expect both signals to be HIGH.

Comment: Is it possible you're not pulling up the RESET line? (edit: og1L beat me).

Comment: Sam3x8e has internal pull-up resistors on reset pins, so why should I add additional ones? I tested those pins with multimetr and it is 3.3 volts there. Here is my schematic for reset pins, I use a jumper to select which reset pin I want to use: http://i65.tinypic.com/24fiwwp.png

Comment: @uint128_t  You may be right about the lack of pull-up.  I don't see the pull-up on the schematic snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

It is necessary to connect gnd from usb-uart bridge to gnd on pcb, I was just using rx - tx line. When the Atmel-Ice was connected it provides ground from pcb to PC usb port through JTAG connector, that`s why it was working.